# Create custom type of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, python-typing

I created a simple dataclass which looks like this:

```
@dataclass
class DeviceLink:
    device_name: str 
    interface_name: str
    .....
```

In my functions I receive and return a dictionary which has runtime defined key names (strings) and DeviceLink instances in values.
In every function I use type annotations like these:

```
def parse(interfaces: dict[str, DeviceLink]) -> dict[str, DeviceLink]:
```

Can I create some custom type in Python which would represent dict[str, DeviceLink] ?

Comment: A TypeAlias? `Foo: TypeAlias = dict[str, DeviceLink]` https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeAlias

Comment: `CustomDict = dict[str, DeviceLink]` `def parse(interfaces: CustomDict)`…?

Comment: you can create a class witch inherits from dict that automatically casts the value to a DeviceLink

Comment: @deceze thanks mate, this is a simple and clean solution

Comment: @IainShelvington good to know there is TypeAlias, seems that it's the best practice to follow in 3.10